# Ubuntu 18.10 after repartition booting slowly

Tags: 18.10

I was running out of space in Ubuntu 18.10 so i did re partition .During that process i deleted swap area and extended partition and recreated swap area.Later when i tried to reboot Ubuntu it is taking more than 2 mins to reboot .Earlier i was happening in just 5 sec.Need inputs to proceed further.

```
Thanks-Arun
```

Comment: Did you remove the swap line from `/etc/fstab` - or at least comment it out ?

Comment: The UUID of your swap partition has changed. Check UUID with `lsblk -f` and edit `/etc/fstab` accordingly.

Comment: No @SorenA . i was having unallocated space of 10 gb . I want to to extend the partition of Ubuntu so i removed swap area and added more space to ubuntu and recreated swap area and reboot the system

Comment: Then do as @mook765 writes above ...